# Renaming files in bash with numbered filenames

Tags: bash, copy-paste, file-rename

In one folder, I have many files with names such as MR000001, MR000002, etc. up to MR000070. I have many folders with such files. I want to copy all of the files to one folder and rename them so that the numbers continue to increase. For example, when copying the second batch of 70, I'd like to rename the files such that they start at 71 and go to 140; when copying the third batch, I'd like their names to start at 141 and go to 210. How can I accomplish this with a bash script? So far, I have this:

```
for f in MR0000*;
do 
  cp "$f" "";
done
```

I think I should be able to fill in the empty quote with something to accomplish what I want, but I don't know what.

Comment: You can also use `printf -v` and take advantage of the `printf` format string to create the filename, numerically padded to a set number of digits. e.g. `declare -i cnt=0; for i in path/to/files/*; do printf -v newname "MR%5d" "$cnt"; mv "$i" "$newname"; $((cnt++)); done`

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```
dst_dir=where/you/want/these/files/to/end/up/
dst_filenumber=0
for src_dir in where/they/are/now/1 where/they/are/now/2 ; do
  for src_filepath in "$src_dir"/MR0000* ; do
    (( dst_filenumber++ ))
    dst_filename="$(printf MR%06d "$dst_filenumber")"
    cp "$src_filepath" "$dst_dir/$dst_filename"
  done
done
```